# jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate not aplicable error

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

```java
public void insert(List<Student> students) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO sqlDB.Student VALUES(?,?,?)";
    ArrayList<Object[]> sqlargs = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(Student tempstudent : students) {
        Object[] studentData = {tempstudent.getRollNo(),tempstudent.getName(),tempstudent.getAddress()};
        sqlargs.add(studentData);
    }
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, sqlargs);
    System.out.println("Batch Update Completed-->");
}
```

Error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
ApplicationContext is Loaded
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method batchUpdate(String, BatchPreparedStatementSetter) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Object[]>)

    at com.jdbc.dao.StudentDAOimpl.insert(StudentDAOimpl.java:76)
    at com.jdbc.service.StudentDAOHelper.setUpStudentTable(StudentDAOHelper.java:35)
    at com.jdbc.test.Runner.main(Runner.java:21)
```

I was trying to insert a batch of student data into the database using `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()`. Above is my method and also the error that I'm getting. As of now I only learned about Spring and JDBC. Is there any other way of using `batchupdate` interface?

Comment: Does it make a difference when you instantiate `sqlargs` like this: `List<Object[]> sqlargs = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes it says : '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Comment: Then try `List<Object[]> sqlargs = new ArrayList<Object[]>()`. (or a newer Java version ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void batchInsert(final List<Student> students) {
    
    String sql ="INSERT INTO sqlDB.Student VALUES(?,?,?)";
    
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            
            Student student=students.get(i);
            
            ps.setInt(1, student.getRollNo());
            ps.setString(2, student.getName());
            ps.setNString(3, student.getAddress());
        }

        public int getBatchSize() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return students.size();
        }
        
        
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear. Does this code solve your problem? If yes, maybe you can [edit] it and add some explanation as to why and how it solves your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).